# error: 'else' without 'if - Cant find solution

Tags: java

//I know the coordinates arnt right ill fix them after i can get it complied but i can't figure out why it keeps giving me that message

```
public class DiceRoller
Public static void main(String[] args
{



 if (dice1 == 1)

            StdDraw.square(.5, .4, .2);
            StdDraw.circle(.3, .5, .035);

         else if (dice1 == 2)

            StdDraw.square(.5, .4, .2);
            StdDraw.circle(.3, .45, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.3, .55, .035);

         else if (dice1 == 3)

            StdDraw.square(.5, .4, .2);
            StdDraw.circle(.3, .55, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.3, .45, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.3, .50, .035);

         else if (dice1 == 4)

            StdDraw.square(.5, .4, .2);
            StdDraw.circle(.25, .55, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.25, .40, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.75, .55, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.75, .40, .035);

         else if (dice1 == 5)

            StdDraw.square(.5, .4, .2);
            StdDraw.circle(.25, .55, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.25, .40, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.75, .55, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.75, .55, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.3, .5, .035);

         else if (dice1 == 6)

            StdDraw.square(.5, .4, .2);
            StdDraw.circle(.25, .50, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.25, .60, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.25, .40, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.75, .60, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.75, .40, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.75, .50, .035);

         if (dice2 == 1)

            StdDraw.square(.5, .7, .2);
            StdDraw.circle(.3, .5, .035);

         else if (dice2 == 2)

            StdDraw.square(.5, .7, .2);
            StdDraw.circle(.3, .45, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.3, .55, .035);

         else if (dice2 == 3)

            StdDraw.square(.5, .7, .2);
            StdDraw.circle(.3, .55, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.3, .45, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.3, .50, .035);
         else if (dice2 == 4)

            StdDraw.square(.5, .7, .2);
            StdDraw.circle(.25, .55, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.25, .40, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.75, .55, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.75, .40, .035);

         else if (dice2 == 5)

            StdDraw.square(.5, .7, .2);
            StdDraw.circle(.25, .55, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.25, .40, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.75, .55, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.75, .55, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.3, .5, .035);

         else if (dice2 == 6)
            StdDraw.square(.5, .7, .2);
            StdDraw.circle(.25, .50, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.25, .60, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.25, .40, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.75, .60, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.75, .40, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.75, .50, .035);
           }
```

Comment: Which message you are talking about ? Please ask question with proper details?

Answer (score 3):

You need to put your `if` inside the brackets `{}` like this:

```
if (dice1 == 2)
{    //should be enclosed since there are more than one statement to be executed
            StdDraw.square(.5, .4, .2);
            StdDraw.circle(.3, .45, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.3, .55, .035);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> error: 'else' without 'if

```
if (dice1 == 1)
{
            StdDraw.square(.5, .4, .2);
            StdDraw.circle(.3, .5, .035);
}
         else if (dice1 == 2)
{
            StdDraw.square(.5, .4, .2);
            StdDraw.circle(.3, .45, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.3, .55, .035);
}
................
```

Should be in braces. Since it contains more than one statement.

Answer (score 1):

Start and end each if and else-if statement with curly braces

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you mixed up Python and Java. In Python, you indicate a block by indenting, but this doesn't work for Java. In Java, you use curly braces (`{}`) to indicate a code block. That means you should add curly braces to your code:

```
if (dice1 == 1) {

            StdDraw.square(.5, .4, .2);
            StdDraw.circle(.3, .5, .035);
} else if (dice1 == 2) {

            StdDraw.square(.5, .4, .2);
            StdDraw.circle(.3, .45, .035);
            StdDraw.circle(.3, .55, .035);
} else if (blah blah blah) {
    blah blah blah
} ...
```

Now your code should work properly. You ask, "Why doesn't the error say '{} expected' or something like that?". That is because if you write this code in Java:

```
 if (dice1 == 1)
        StdDraw.square(.5, .4, .2);
        StdDraw.circle(.3, .5, .035);
 else if (dice1 == 2)
        StdDraw.square(.5, .4, .2);
        StdDraw.circle(.3, .45, .035);
        StdDraw.circle(.3, .55, .035);
```

It actually means:

```
if (dice1 == 1) {
        StdDraw.square(.5, .4, .2);
} 
StdDraw.circle(.3, .5, .035);
else if (dice1 == 2) {
        StdDraw.square(.5, .4, .2);
}
StdDraw.circle(.3, .45, .035);
StdDraw.circle(.3, .55, .035);
```

Now you understand why it says you don't have an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

[if Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) states that

> The opening and closing braces are optional, provided that the "then" clause contains only one statement

You will have to enclose your `if` and `else if` block in braces `{}`.

```
if (dice1 == 1) { // <---- braces
    StdDraw.square(.5, .4, .2);
    StdDraw.circle(.3, .5, .035);
} // <---- braces
else if (dice1 == 2) {
    ...
}
```